# How to check if all rows match a criteria in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, while-loop

I want to check if a certain field of all rows match a criteria.

So if all rows has in the Status field 'RUN' as value then echo "Success".
If there is one row with END as value then echo "Fail":

I'm guessing I need a loop and an IF statement ? 
I was thinking something like this but it doesnt return anything:

```
while($source_row = mysqli_fetch_array($source_selection)){
    if ( ($source_row['Stat']) == ("Run" ) {
        echo "Success<br />";
    } else
        echo "Fail";
}
```

I don't want to echo each row, I want all rows to match a criteria then echo, if one doesn't match a criteria then echo as well.

Comment: Just a suggestion: this would likely be more suitable for a check in your SQL query. It's only a slight addition, but it makes for less php code, which is easier to follow. If you do want to do it in php, I suggest using `array_filter()` and counting the resulting elements. Good luck!

Comment: So where are we with this question?

Comment: thank you for your suggestion @JoelHinz, i might look into SQL too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

First of all you have to fetch all rows with `mysqli_fetch_all()`. After this I extract only the Stat column with `array_column()`. Then I just simply `array_fill()` an array with X values as you have in `$states` with the value "Run". And check if every value is equals.

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_all($source_selection, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$states = array_column($result, "Stat");

if($states == array_fill(0, count($states), "Run")) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you. 
Now im going to try to understand what it exactly does.

Comment: @R2D2 You're welcome. It's not the common way, but it does the job. Basically as I already explained in my answer. 1. You get all rows at once into one singe array `$result`. 2. Then you extract only the column `Stat` from your array. So now you have all `Stat`'s values from every row. 3. Then you compare this array with an array, which you fill with the same amount of elements with the value `Run`. And if every element of both arrays are equals the if statement is true

Comment: Oh yea I see now, very clever !

Answer (score 1):

There are some error in the code and you can use the count to match -

```
$count = 0;
while($source_row = mysqli_fetch_array($source_selection)){
  if ($source_row['Stat'] == "Run" ) {
      $count++;
  }
}
if($count != mysqli_num_rows($source_selection)) {
  echo "Fail";
} else echo "Success";
```

Comment: I dont get any output when i do this.

Comment: hi @b0s3 could u help me again please?
I edited your code and tried to make a function of it but im not getting the expected result. 

Im trying to get "Success" when every record has 0 as Delay value, if its different then its "Fail". But im getting "success" when a record is not 0. 

https://gist.github.com/R2D2-05/da1cc473a68dccc3be35

Answer (score 1):

For best performance you can do it directy on the SQL:

```
select count(*) from table where Stat <> 'Run';
```

And then test the returning value to check that is greater than zero.

To do it with php you should know that when you find an error you can stop the iterations. The code would look like that:

```
while($source_row = mysqli_fetch_array($source_selection)){
   if ( $source_row['Stat'] != "Run" ){
      $fail = true;
      break;
   }
}

if ($fail) {
  echo "Fail";
} else
  echo "Success";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$success=true;
while($source_row = mysqli_fetch_array($source_selection)){
  if ( ($source_row['Stat']) != ("Run" ) {
    $success=false;
  }
}
if ($success) {
  echo "Success";
} else {
  echo "Fail";
}
```

Comment: If already 1 value is Run all other values can be something else and it won't work

Comment: Ooops, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: There is error in -  `if ( ($source_row['Stat']) != ("Run" )`